# How to extract bz2 file in php

Tags: php, extract, bzip2

I have exported an SQL file from a database by using `phpmyadmin`. The file is named `final.sql.bz2` and then I uploaded it onto my Live Server.

The question is, how could I extract that file by using PHP code? I tried to search for that on google, but not getting any result. How could I `unzip` it?

Comment: why you want unzip sql file?

Comment: my phpmyadmin not allow more then 5 mb of file for import, so i want to run it from php side

Comment: so you can zip that file normally and import from phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think that is no need to use php code for zip sql file,you can zip that file normally and import it in php myadmin.

Comment: yes, but when i make zip then it will make 19 mb of zip file and i use shared server then it not allow to upload me more then 5 mb.

Comment: no,tell me your original sql file size.

Comment: 54.8 mb SQL file and 7.1 mb of zip file

Comment: your file extention is final.sql.bz2 right?

Comment: Do one thing take a backup of your sql file extention like this (final.sql)

Comment: yes `final.sql.bz2` and take backup also `final.sql`

Comment: take a backup file extention like .sql only

Comment: yes, get backup `final.sql`

Comment: Now .sql file size ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `bzip` function from PHP not the `zip` functions they are different.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bzip2.php

Or if its possible you can use `exec` to execute the `bunzip2` command to extract your file from your archive:

```
bunzip2 [DATEI].bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to extract bz2 in **shared hosting** where `tar` couldnt help me to extract (got error with bzip2 and lbzip2, and I could not install anything or do sudo...)

I solved it by creating a php file and run it from command line (of course you can modify the script to use it online too).

**bunzip2.php**

```
<?php
function decompress($data)
 {
     // Decompress the file
     if (@file_exists($data)) {
         $bz = bzopen($data, 'r');
         $uncompressed = '';
         // Read the uncompressed data.
         while (!feof($bz)) {
             $uncompressed .= bzread($bz, 4096);
         }
         // Close the Bzip2 compressed file and write
         // the data to the uncompressed file.
         bzclose($bz);
         if (stripos($data, '.tbz2') !== false) {
             $newFile = str_replace('.tbz2', '.tar', $data);
         } else {
             if (stripos($data, '.tbz') !== false) {
                 $newFile = str_replace('.tbz', '.tar', $data);
             } else {
                 $newFile = str_replace('.bz2', '', $data);
             }
         }
         file_put_contents($newFile, $uncompressed);
         return $newFile;
         // Else, decompress the string
     } else {
         return bzdecompress($data);
     }
 }

decompress($argv[1]);
?>
```

> php bunzip2.php my.tar.bz2

(I just searched for bz2+php on github, I did not check the code in detail but it does the work ;)